# Merging various DataFrames from Same Column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

I am merging two dataframes together by a common key column (first column), however I want to add the same columns once again based on the second column from the same previous column:

```
clusering_matrix_example <- data.frame(BGC = c("BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC3", "BGC4"), Family = c("10","20","30","40"))
network_matrix_example <- data.frame(BGC1 = c("BGC1", "BGC1", "BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC2", "BGC2", "BGC3", "BGC3", "BGC3", "BGC4", "BGC4", "BGC4"),
                                     BGC2 = c("BGC2", "BGC3", "BGC4", "BGC1", "BGC3", "BGC4", "BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC4", "BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC3"),
                                     score = c(1,2,3,1,4,5,2,4,6,3,5,6))
network_output_example <- merge(network_matrix_example, clusering_matrix_example, by.x= "BGC1", by.y = "BGC")

network_output_example <- merge(network_matrix_example, clusering_matrix_example, by.x= "BGC2", by.y = "BGC")
```

## Example of Output of First DF

```
BGC1  | BGC2 | score |Family
BGC1    BGC2    1     10
BGC1    BGC3    2     10
BGC1    BGC4    3     10
BGC2    BGC1    1     20
BGC2    BGC3    4     20
BGC2    BGC4    5     20
BGC3    BGC1    2     30
BGC3    BGC2    4     30
BGC3    BGC4    6     30
BGC4    BGC1    3     40
BGC4    BGC2    5     40
BGC4    BGC3    6     40
```

## Desired Output DF

```
BGC1  | BGC2 | score |Family1 | Family2
BGC1    BGC2    1     10        20
BGC1    BGC3    2     10        30
BGC1    BGC4    3     10        40
BGC2    BGC1    1     20        10
BGC2    BGC3    4     20        30
BGC2    BGC4    5     20        40
BGC3    BGC1    2     30        10
BGC3    BGC2    4     30        20
BGC3    BGC4    6     30        40
BGC4    BGC1    3     40        10
BGC4    BGC2    5     40        20
BGC4    BGC3    6     40        40
```

These are possibly also of different length, so would I do merge all = TRUE?

Comment: I don't want to replace it, I just want to add it on once again as a secondary column, I don't know if this makes sense. Like I would get the first dataframe and then add the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the name in the second merge

```
clusering_matrix_example <- data.frame(BGC = c("BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC3", "BGC4"), Family = c("10","20","30","40"))

ne1 <- data.frame(BGC1 = c("BGC1", "BGC1", "BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC2", "BGC2", "BGC3", "BGC3", "BGC3", "BGC4", "BGC4", "BGC4"),
                                     BGC2 = c("BGC2", "BGC3", "BGC4", "BGC1", "BGC3", "BGC4", "BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC4", "BGC1", "BGC2", "BGC3"),
                                     score = c(1,2,3,1,4,5,2,4,6,3,5,6))

ne2 <- merge(ne1, clusering_matrix_example, by.x= "BGC1", by.y = "BGC")

network_output_example <- merge(ne2, clusering_matrix_example, by.x= "BGC2", by.y = "BGC")
```

Comment: would it be possible to add arguments such as all.x = TRUE if I want them to be all the same size as ne1?

Comment: Yeah, why not? But actually ne1,ne2 and network_output are all the same size (12 obs). But for another case, if you add those arguments rows will be added to the output, even when there is no matching between x and y (in case of all.x), those cases will be added as NA. Was that your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- merge(network_matrix_example, clusering_matrix_example, by.x= c("BGC1"), by.y = "BGC")

df2 <- merge(df1, clusering_matrix_example, by.x= c("BGC2"), by.y = "BGC")

names(df2)[names(df2)=="Family.x"] <- "Family1"
names(df2)[names(df2)=="Family.y"] <- "Family2"

df3 <- df2[,c("BGC1","BGC2","score","Family1","Family2")]

df4 <- df3[with(df3, order(BGC1,BGC2,score,Family1,Family2)),]
```

Looks like your desired output.